# Export password protected PDF from QGIS

Tags: pdf, password-protection, qgis, protected, copy-protection

Is there a way to export a map as a PDF so that it is immediately read-only? Or generally protected? I want to do this in Qgis. So that I can directly export an PDF that is protected.

I didn't find any settings in Qgis